# How to restrict join clause via where clause

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have two tables, `comment` and `user`. Here is my structure:

```
// comment
+----+---------+---------+---------+
| id | id_user | id_post | content |
+----+---------+---------+---------+

// user
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
```

I want to access the name of user from `user` table (instead of `id_user`). here is my query:

```
select c.content, u.name from comment c inner join user u on c.id_user=u.id;
```

It gives me this structure:

```
+---------+------+
| content | name |
+---------+------+
```

The structure is fine, but I need to just select the comments that are belong to post `x`. In other word, how can I use `id_post` in my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`where`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm):

```
select c.content, u.name
  from comment c inner join user u on c.id_user = u.id
  where c.id_post = <x>
```

Comment: I knew it, Just I did not know the syntax,  +1 voteup for you. tnx

Comment: My question was your lucky question, you have `10k` rep now :-)

Answer (score 2):

How about using the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT c.content, u.name
FROM comment c INNER JOIN user u
ON c.id_user=u.id
WHERE c.id_post = x
```

Comment: I knew it, Just I did not know the syntax, +1 voteup for you. tnx